# CouchDB 1.6.1 replication to bluemix.cloudant.com

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I am trying to replicate a local couchDB version 1.6.1 to cloudant.com which is in IBM cloud.
I previously had it working withh www.cloudant.com before IBM got their paws on it.

I can curl to the cloudant address no problem, but when I update my replicator design document variable target with the same url , the replication is not working

target: "https://username:password@host/target"  target is the name of the database

Any ideas would be most helpful?
Do i need to upgrade my local db.

Comment: Sorry I think I found the solution. The entries in the _replicator databse had a _replication_state as error due to them timing out when cloudant moved to ibm cloud. I deleted the entry and recreated them and the replication is now working

Comment: "Before IBM got their paws on it" ... That's ancient history.. IBM has owned Cloudant since 2014.